# Backup copy of shell script

Tags: linux, shell-script, backup

```bash
#!/bin/bash 
echo "Menu" 
echo "1. Backup file"
echo "2. Quit" 
echo "Enter Choice" 
read Choice

case $Choice" in 
       1) while : 
               echo "Enter file name" 
               read file name 
               do 
               if [ -f $filename]
               then 
                      current_time=$(date."+%Y.%m.%d")
                      back_up= "Backup"
                      new_file=$filename.$back_up.$current_time
                      echo "New file name is:" "$new_file"
                      cp $new_file $HOME 

              else 
                      echo "file does not exists"
              fi 
done 
                    ;;
         2) echo "Program Terminated" 
                 exit;;
esac
```

I need to create a shell script that backs up a script file input by the user and saves it to the home directory with a new extension date & backup as well as checking that the file exists. The first part seems to work fine, but then I receive a message saying `cp:cannot stat no file or directory`.

Comment: Looks like you only posted part of the script, and I can see at least one syntax error, a logic flaw and some questionable looping in that which you have presented. I’d suggest posting the full thing to allow for a proper inspection.

Comment: i just updated the script. Could you explain to me where i am going wrong?

Comment: You seem to have a typo: You state `read file name`, implying you want to read two tokens, but later on use `filename` which of then course is an empty variable.

Comment: Hi i fixed the typo but its still no saving a copy of the file. Is there any other way i can get it done/ fix it?

Comment: You are missing tons of quotes, I suggest checking out https://shellcheck.net

Comment: It still doesn't work

Answer (score 1):

Let us ignore the quotes, syntax etc remarks and also the fact that the tag Kali-linux is inappropriate, because it is irrelevant  here and Kali is for experienced users.

```
#!/bin/bash 
echo "Menu" 
echo "1. Backup file"
echo "2. Quit" 
echo "Enter Choice" 
read Choice
```

So, your choice is now either `1` or `2` (or a lot of other different inputs that we just ignore)

```
case "$Choice" in 
       1) while : 
               echo "Enter file name" 
               read file name 
               do
```

You read 2 variables `file` and `name`, neither of which you use in the rest of the script. You probably meant something like this:

```
       (1) while read -p "Enter file name" filename ; do
```

`if [ -f $filename]` is always true, because `filename` is empty in your script. If you had read `filename` instead of `file name`, the result would have been

```
bash: [: missing `]'
```

A space must be inserted before the `]`.  (might as well do the quoting)

```
               if [ -f "$filename" ] ; then
                      current_time=$(date "+%Y.%m.%d")
                      back_up="Backup"
                      new_file="$filename.$back_up.$current_time" # quotes
                      echo "New file name is: $new_file"
                      cp $new_file $HOME
```

You are entering a filename (say `foo`) and you are copying `foo.Backup.2021.03.15` to your home directory. Does that file exist? probably not, because you get the message  `cp: cannot stat foo.Backup.2021.03.15: No such file or directory` So, you probably want to copy `foo`.

```
cp "$filename"  "$HOME/$new_file"
```

Note that you could easily have found that out yourself by looking at the filename or by adding an echo before the `cp`. Echos are great for finding errors in your script.

```
                   echo "Copying $filename to $HOME/$new_file"
                   cp "$filename"  "$HOME/$new_file"
              else 
                      echo "file does not exists"
              fi 
            done 
             ;;
```

You will need to terminate this while -loop with `^D`.  I hope you weren't expecting the second case statement to exit your loop.

```
         2) echo "Program Terminated" 
                 exit;;
esac
```

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

Let's assume that the user actually do want to back up a file if they run your script.  This means that the interactive menu is not needed. (Also note your quoting error at the very start of the `case` statement.)

Let's assume that the user can type the pathnames of the files they want to back up on the command line of your script, either as whole pathnames (possibly using tab-completion, which your script does not allow them to do), or as shell globbing patterns (which your script also does not allow).  This means that the second interactive `read` call and the loop can be replaced by using the arguments given to the script.

So, we get

```bash
#!/bin/bash

if [ "$#" -eq 0 ]; then
    cat >&2 <<END_USAGE
This script backs up files and places backups in your
home directory with a timestamp as filename suffix.

Usage:

    $0 file [...]

END_USAGE
    exit 1
fi

printf -v suffix 'backup.%(%Y.%m.%d)T' -1

for pathname do
    if [ ! -f "$pathname" ]; then
        printf '"%s" is not found or is not a regular file, ' "$pathname"
        printf 'will not back it up\n'
        continue
    fi >&2

    printf -v newname '%s.%s' "${pathname##*/}" "$suffix"

    if cp -i "$pathname" "$HOME/$newname"; then
        printf 'backed up "%s" as "%s" in your home directory\n' \
            "$pathname" "$newname"
    else
        printf 'failed backing up "%s" as "%s" in your home directory\n' \
            "$pathname" "$newname" >&2
    fi
done
```

The only reason `bash` executes this is to be able to use `printf -v` in a couple of places, and to get rid of having to run `date` to get a timestamp (this would work with `bash` release 4.2 or later).

I'm outputting a short info text about how to use the script and what it does if the script is run without any command line arguments.  The script teminates after outputting this info.

If given command line arguments (`$#` is greater than zero), these are iterated over.

In each iteration we check to make sure that the given argument exists as a regular file (or a symbolic link to a regular file), and skip ahead to the next if it doesn't.

Then' the new filename is created using the variable `suffix` (created earlier), and the base name of the current value of `pathname`.

We run the copy with `cp -i`, so that the user has a chance to say "no" to overwriting  a file, just in case that backup file already exists.

Testing:

```
$ ./script script
backed up "script" as "script.backup.2021.03.15" in your home directory
$ ./script scriptantoeh
"scriptantoeh" is not found or is not a regular file will not back it up
$ ./script file{1..3}
"file1" is not found or is not a regular file will not back it up
"file2" is not found or is not a regular file will not back it up
"file3" is not found or is not a regular file will not back it up
$ ./script script
overwrite /home/myself/script.backup.2021.03.15? y
backed up "script" as "script.backup.2021.03.15" in your home directory
```